# php substr_replace space with hyphen?

Tags: php, replace, substr

i have this

```
echo "<div class='weather " . $cell->textContent ."'>";
```

this works fine when textContent is just one word like "sunny". However if the current weather is e.g. "partially cloudy" i get of course two classes applied (.partially and .cloudy instead of .partially-cloudy.

How can I make sure whenever there are two (or more) words contained in textContent I replace all spaces with a hyphen?

This does not work:

```
echo "<div class='weather " . substr_replace(" ", "-", $cell->textContent) ."'>";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
echo "<div class='weather " . str_replace(" ", "-", $cell->textContent) ."'>";
```